# How to give condition to the column after getting the max of group of some columns in the specific column?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: This is the table]

I have multiple labels for every image ID. Every label has its own row and unique ID in the table. I have got the maximum percentage value of the label 'car' in the table after grouping them by image ID. But I don't know how to get the rows only with the condition in which the max percentage of the 'car' label of specific image ID is less than 40.

```
select used_car_image_id, count(object_label), max(percentage) 
from individual_used_cars_image_label
where object_label = 'car'
group by used_car_image_id
```

I expect the tables to show used_car_image_id, count(object_label), max(percentage) where the max(percentage) will be less than 40. And it shouldn't include any image ID in which any label named 'car' has more than 40 percentage.

Answer (score 2):

use having

```
select used_car_image_id, count(object_label), max(percentage) 
from individual_used_cars_image_label
where object_label = 'car'
group by used_car_image_id
having max(percentage)<40
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this too --

```
SELECT u.image_id,u.image_url,l.object_label,max(l.percentage) max_car_percentage 
FROM `individual_used_cars_image_label` l 
INNER JOIN individual_used_cars u 
ON l.used_car_image_id=u.image_id 
WHERE l.object_label = 'car' 
GROUP BY u.image_id 
HAVING max_car_percentage < 40
```